# Big Oh notation ambiguity

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I have a doubt with the usage of the Big Oh notation.
I made a toy example to explain it. 
Consider the following easy lemmas:

**Lemma 1.** If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n = n + O(1)$ for all $n \geq 1$, then $\tfrac1{x} \sum_{n \leq x} a_n = \tfrac1{2} x + O(1)$ for all $x \geq 1$.

**Lemma 2.** If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n = \mu n + O(1)$ for all $n \geq 1$, for some constant $\mu >0$, then $\tfrac1{x} \sum_{n \leq x} a_n = \tfrac{\mu}{2} x + O(1)$ for all $x \geq 1$.

**Lemma 3.** If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n = \mu n + O(1)$ for all $n \geq 1$, for some constant $\mu >0$, then $\tfrac1{x} \sum_{n \leq x} a_n = \tfrac{\mu}{2} x + O_\mu(1)$ for all $x \geq 1$.

I guess we all agree that Lemma 2 is sloppy, since the implied constant in the second Big Oh depends on $\mu$ and making that not explicit could lead to a mistake (for example if using Lemma 2 with several values of $\mu$). In this regard, Lemma 3 explicitly states that the error term is not uniform in $\mu$, writing $O_\mu$ instead of just $O$, so it leaves no space for ambiguity and it is strongly preferred to Lemma 2. My doubt is with Lemma 1: the implied constant in the second Big Oh depends on the implied constant in the first Big Oh, however this is stated in no way. Clearly, this is a trivial example, but in more complicated situations this dependence may go unnoticed and lead to the same kind of errors of the formulation of Lemma 2.

My question is: What is the standard way to make the statements of lemmas like Lemma 1 precise?

Comment: The whole point of using $O(\cdots)$ notation is to ignore the constants in those terms. It's perfectly reasonable to want information about those constants, but trying to tweak $O(\cdots)$ notation to fulfill that need isn't an optimal approach.

Comment: @AntonioVargas The problem is that I do not see an approach avoiding Big Oh notation except for writing down all the constants explicitly, which is much more annoying in my opinion...

Comment: Did you forget an $x$ in Lemma 2?  As for your doubt, in Lemma 2 there is no constant that works for all values of $\mu$.  Therefore it is appropriate to use the parameterized big oh.  But in Lemma 1 there is no $\mu$.  (In fact, there is no parameter.) Hence, the parametrized big oh is out of place.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Right, I forgot an $x$, thanks. I understand that in Lemma 1 there are no parameters. However, the implied constant in the second Big Oh depends on the implied constant in the first Big Oh.

Comment: And why is that a problem?  By assumption there's a single constant that, for every $n$, bounds the error term of $a_n$. Therefore there's a constant that bounds the error term of the summation.  The second constant obviously depends on the first, but in terms of big oh notation it doesn't make a difference.  In the case of Lemma 2 the situation is different, because you want to make a claim that holds for all $\mu$ and you want to stress that, "for every $\mu$ there is a constant such that..." instead of, "there is a constant such that for every $\mu$."

Comment: @FabioSomenzi The problems come in more complicated situations. Let us say that instead of Lemma 1 we have a really non-trivial result "Theorem A" which we need to apply to a family of sequences of $a_n(\delta)$, depending on some new parameter $\delta$. Now understanding if the error term in the thesis of Theorem A depends or not on the error terms in the hypothesis is necessary, and if Theorem A is stated like Lemma 1, then one has no other way than looking through the whole (non-trivial) proof of Theorem A...

Comment: I'm sure there are more complicated situations, but I fail to see how they differ in a significant way from your example.  Either you proved that all error terms are bounded by one constant and that is enough to complete the bigger proof, or you need more information about those error terms than just a constant bound.  (Say, they are the terms of a geometric series with ratio less than one.  Sure, they are bounded by a constant, but, crucially, their sum is also bounded by a constant.)  The parametrization issue is largely othogonal to this.